# Creating a grid in wx Erlang

Tags: erlang, wxwidgets, erl, wxgrid, wxerlang

I am trying to create an interface with Erlang. I want to use the wx grid module but cannot find anywhere to learn how exactly to start using this module.

Answer (score 1):

With a simple google search you can find its official documentation:

- [Erlang wxWidget](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/wx/chapter.html)
- [Erlang wxGrid](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/wxGrid.html)

Also you can open an Erlang shell and type `wx:demo()`. It opens a graphical window with lots of examples, including buttons, canvas, grids and etc which shows you the code as well as its graphical results.